# Can CURRENT_TIMESTAMP change within an INSERT or UPDATE command?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with a few dates (among other things) that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE message (
    created_on DATEIMTE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    send_on DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modified_on DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    status CHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 'V',
    status_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ...
);
```

When I do an `INSERT INTO`, I generally do not define the `modified_on` field since the default makes sense. I may change the `send_on` value if I do not want my message to be sent immediately.

So an insertion could look like this:

```
INSERT INTO message
    (send_on)
    VALUES ('2017-08-31 14:31:22');
```

Later, the user may ask to change the `send_on` field. At that point, I run an UPDATE statement as follow:

```
UPDATE message
    SET send_on = <user-defined-date>,
        modified_on = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE id = 123;
```

This case is fine since I modified only one date.

Now, at the time the user makes a modification, I may have to also change the `status` field. That would translate into something like this:

```
UPDATE message
    SET send_on = <user-defined-date>,
        modified_on = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        status = <new-status>,
        status_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE id = 123;
```

In that last `UPDATE` statement and less obvious, in the `INSERT INTO` statement above, I am setting more than one `DATETIME` field to the value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (2 in that `UPDATE`, 3 in the `INSERT INTO` through the `DEFAULT` definitions).

My question is: will all the columns assigned the value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` always receive the exact same value whenever it gets used more than once? Or will each column determine the value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` once it gets executed and hence, could be a second later (if we were a few ms away from the next second, it can easily happen.)

So far I have not seen a problem, but that does not mean it could not happen. Is that specific case properly documented somewhere in the MySQL reference?

Comment: The timestamps will be seconds (potentially) off based on their execution.

Comment: replace `modified_on = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with an auto update for that timing column  `modified_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: This means that every tyime the row is updated it automatically records the time doneso.

Comment: @Martin Sure, that can be done. All the "modified" type of columns I really have are all specific to one or a few fields so I don't update those each time... Also that was not the point of my question. :-)

Comment: @AlexisWilke I know, that's why it's  comment not an answer, but it saves you writing out and dealing with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if you build that handle into the SQL itself rather than the code. `:-p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now),

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, NOW() returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for SYSDATE(), which returns the exact time at which it executes.

So `current_timestamp` (which is a [synonym for `now()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp)) will have the same value even if the query runs for hours. It is so relevant that it will actually even keep that value if the query gets [replicated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-functions.html) to a different server.

Comment: I think it was important, indeed! There are several cases where I would like to compare my dates and was thinking that they should be equal but could not be absolutely sure. This looks very good though.